# Getting initilized object instead of what the service sent

Tags: java, json, spring, post

I'm using `POST` to send an obejct as a parameter to a method in a service. The method is invoking each time but spring is returning me an initilized object (with zeros and nulls) instead of what the serivce returned.

With postman its working great:

I send:

```
{
  "userId": 10,
  "resourceType": 11,
  "privilegeValues": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

I get:

```
{
  "ErrorCode": 10,
  "ErrorDescription": null,
  "Privilages": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

C#:

IPrivilagesRest:

```
namespace RestAPI
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://microsoft.wcf.documentation")]
    public interface IPrivilagesRest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetUserPrivilages", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        UserPrivilegesResponse GetUserPrivilages(UserPrivilegesRequest userPrivilegesRequest);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/IsAlive", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        bool isAlive();
    }
}
```

PrivilagesProvider:

```
namespace RestAPI
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class PrivilagesProvider : IPrivilagesRest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// get privilages related to a specific user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userPrivilegesRequest"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public UserPrivilegesResponse GetUserPrivilages(UserPrivilegesRequest userPrivilegesRequest)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(userPrivilegesRequest==null?"Null":"Not null!!!!!!!");
            return new UserPrivilegesResponse() { Privilages = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },ErrorCode=10 };
        }

        public bool isAlive()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            UserPrivilegesRequest request=new UserPrivilegesRequest();
            UserPrivilegesResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:12345/PrivilagesServiceNamespace/PrivilagesService/GetUserPrivilages",request, UserPrivilegesResponse.class);
            log.info("respose: "+ response);
        };
    }
}
```

UserPrivilegesResponse.java

```
@ToString
public class UserPrivilegesResponse {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int ErrorCode;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int ErrorDescription;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int[] Privilages;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay In the WCF C# project and the Spring JAVA project I wrote different type for the same property of the Response object.
Spring could not parse it so it gave me empty initilized (zero) object.

**I recommend everyone to use `@JsonProperty("XXX")` for each property of the response object so Spring will tell you which one he couldnt parse. Thats how I found my error. Use it even if the properties names are the same as `XXX`.**